# how to plot multiple legends from a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to iterate over multiple plots each with their own labels. The legend values are taken from the list 'iou'. The code below only generates 1 label for iou=0.2. Any help is appreciated.

```
iou=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(0,4):
    p=plt.plot(recall[i], precision[i], marker='+')
    plt.legend(p, iou)
plt.title("PR curves")
plt.xlabel("Recall")
plt.ylabel("Precision")
```

Comment: you're calling the whole list in plt.legend - maybe plt.legend(p, iou[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop you'll want to use the `label` attribute of `plt.plot` and only after the loop call to `plt.legend`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

iou=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i in range(0,4):
    ax.plot(recall[i], precision[i], marker='+', label=iou[i])

fig.legend()
ax.set_title("PR curves")
ax.set_xlabel("Recall")
ax.set_ylabel("Precision")
```

A minimal working example could be the following:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iou=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
precision = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(4, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i in range(0,4):
    ax.plot(np.r_[:10], iou[i] * precision[i], marker='+', label=iou[i])

fig.legend()
ax.set_title("PR curves")
ax.set_xlabel("Recall")
ax.set_ylabel("Precision")
```

Which gives the following:

[image]